# Is there any way to get `picture` from OneLogin's `profile` scope?

Tags: onelogin

The OneLogin [OpenID Connect Scopes Documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/scopes) for the `profile` scope shows that there is a `picture` available but with this disclaimer:

> Note, these claims are returned if OneLogin has the information available.

In testing, I never get `picture` back when testing with a user that has a profile photo set. What I get has these attributes only:

```
{
  "id_token": "",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "openid profile",
  "profile": {
    "sub": "",
    "email": "",
    "preferred_username": "",
    "name": "",
    "updated_at": 1614904145,
    "given_name": "",
    "family_name": "",
    "sid": ""
  },
  "expires_at": 1615761073
}
```

Any tips on how to get the additional fields from OneLogin would be appreciated. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to OneLogin's dev support and I got a response in a few hours. I have verified that this works, here it is:

> You should add a parameter to your OIDC app and map it to the field "Profile Picture" and then include the params scope in your ODIC call. (fro more details on scopes see https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/scopes)
>
> Note - what you get back is the URL of an image and it is not a binary blob of the actual photo.